In the US, what has been the general outcome of COVID-19 vaccine-mandate litigation?
Recently, a friend informed me that he knew someone who had won a lawsuit, with a large award for damages, against his employer, which I believe was a private company, because he was dismissed for not getting the COVID-19 vaccine, which was contrary to the company’s vaccination mandate at the time. I did not know which state this litigation took place in, or whether it may have even been in federal court (although I doubt that), but I do know that he was working remotely in what would have been an office job in-person.
Now, it got me wondering, how has litigation against vaccine mandates instituted by private companies ended generally, throughout the US? I assume private companies mostly successfully defended these claims (although I’m more than happy to be proved wrong). If so, which people won cases alleging unlawful treatment, for their dismissal or any other adverse action, due to violating their private employer’s vaccine mandate? Are there any notable examples of cases in which the plaintiff won on a ground that wasn’t related to religious discrimination?
I’m genuinely curious now haha. Thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Is "choosing to remain unvaccinated for a specific disease" a protected class anywhere in the US?

@brhans I like the sarcasm, but I think cases may be brought more along the lines of religious discrimination or breach of contract, or something more along those lines, although I can’t really imagine the fact pattern for the second example, although that’s probably no surprise ’cause I’m not a lawyer aha.

I'm unclear on why there are so many votes to close. The stated reason is that the question's scope needs to be narrowed, which is presumably because there are multiple questions. However, all of the questions are closely related and part of answering a single overarching question of, "How have vaccine mandate lawsuits fared for private businesses?"
